# C# quotes in interpolated string Unexpected character \0022

Tags: c#, c#-6.0, string-interpolation

I've read that you can use expressions in interpolated strings, but escaping quotes does not work.

```
private string sth = $"{String.Join(\"\", Node.stringToType.Keys)}";


Error CS1056: Unexpected character `\0022' (CS1056)
Error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `)', expecting `${', `:', or `}' (CS1525)
```

UPDATE:

The inner expression above was ment to be equivalent to

```
String.Join("", Node.stringToType.Keys)
```

(the two backslashes were for escaping the two double quotes) like that you can insert there any delimiter.

Comment: Your first \ is redundant

Comment: do you really need string interpolation here in the first place?

Comment: Yes it's a long regex and I use it everywhere else, so I guess `String.Format` wouldn't fit in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this

```
private string sth = $"{String.Join("\\", Node.stringToType.Keys)}";
```

This way must work too

```
private string sth = $"{String.Join(@"\", Node.stringToType.Keys)}";
```

Comment: I actually ment the first arg in the Join as an empty string (I'm going to use "|"). That's strange that you don't need to escape it, also the `@` looks like a part of the preceding string.

Answer (score 1):

You should put it as

```
  private string sth = $"{String.Join("\\", Node.stringToType.Keys)}";
```

please, notice that the text within `{...}` should be *correct* C# code

```
  String.Join("\\", Node.stringToType.Keys)
```

As a further improvement, you don't want string interpolation at all:

```
  private string sth = String.Join("\\", Node.stringToType.Keys);
```